# Two examples of compound functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Could you provide an example to distinguish the following two cases:

(a) $f(x(p,q),y(p,q),z(p,q))$

versus

(b) $f(x(p,q),y(p,q),z(p,q),q)$

Surely in (b) $f$ is defined in ${\rm I\!R}^4$ while in (a) $f$ is defined in in ${\rm I\!R}^3$, but for example the expression $3(p+q)$ seems to fit both, because it could be that $x=y=z=p+q$ (this fits (a)) or it could be that $x=y=z=p$ and thus $q$ appears as a fourth variable because of the term $3q$ (this fits (b)).

It is confusing to me. How would one distinguish an expression that depends on $q$ explicitly from another one that depends on $q$ only as a compound function through its arguments $x, y$ or $z$?

Comment: The issue is you are trying to define a function of p and q first, this means there wouldn't necessarily be a unique way of going backwards to obtain a function of just x,y,z.